# Is there a complete list of all compact spaces covered by $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, covering-spaces

I'm interested in compact spaces that are covered by $\mathbb{R}^2$. I know of the torus and the Klein bottle. Is the double-holed torus covered by $\mathbb{R^2}$? Are there any other spaces, or are these the only two compact spaces? Is there a way to show this/is there a complete characterization of all such spaces?

EDIT: I realize from the comments that all spaces (apart from the sphere and the real projective plane) are covered by $\mathbb{R}^2$. I guess then my question then really is the following:

Is there some (maybe geometric) characterization that helps reduce the set of spaces that are covered by $\mathbb{R}^2$?

What I mean is that the double torus is covered by the plane, but (if I understand correctly) the plane needs to have hyperbolic geometry. Say I were only interested in a Euclidean geometry? What about in that case? Is there some characterization for which only the torus, or the torus and the klein bottle are the reasonable covered spaces?

The motivation for this question is coming from a research problem in a very different (non-mathematical) field, but very qualitatively: Say I have data from a manifold $X$. Some data analysis method (that relates to path lifting) reveals a representation of $X$ via some manifold $Y$. I can prove that $Y$ must be covered by $X$. However, in practice, I see that if $X$ is a plane (with Euclidean geometry), then $Y$ is only the torus, so I'm trying to understand if there's some sense in which a torus should be naturally expected.

Comment: Since a covering map is a local homeomorphism then the space has to be surface as well. All compact surfaces have $\mathbb{R}^2$ as universal covering, except for the sphere (which is its own universal covering) and the real projective plane (which has sphere as the universal covering).

Comment: @freakish: Oh. I see. So any $n$-holed torus is also covered by $R^2$. Hmmm. 
This might be a bit vague, but is there some (maybe geometric) characterization that helps reduce the set of spaces? What I mean is that the double torus is covered by the plane, but (if I understand correctly) the plane needs to have hyperbolic geometry. Say I were only interested in a Euclidean geometry? What about in that case? Is there some characterization for which only the torus, or the torus and the klein bottle are the reasonable covered spaces?

Comment: The [uniformization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem) implies that the universal cover of a compact surface must be either a sphere or the plane. So as pointed out in @freakish's comment, it's quicker to list the compact spaces whose universal cover isn't the plane: namely the sphere and the real projective plane. I suspect there is a simpler proof - perhaps freakish could advise on that. (Note: I think the uniformization theorem is needed to address SarthakC's comment.)

Comment: If you are interested in questions about hyperbolic v. euclidean geometry, then you should add riemannian-geometry as a tag and edit your question accordingly. Perhaps you should say a bit more about the context.

Comment: You may want to ask a different question: Which compact surfaces admit Riemannian metrics such that the universal cover with pull-back metric is isometric to the Euclidean plane? The answer to this will be "only the torus and the Klein bottle."

Comment: @RobArthan: I have added some more context, hopefully that helps. This is not my area, so I am having some difficulty in precisely stating my question.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Ah, I think that might be what I'm looking for! Could you elaborate/point me to a reference where I might be able to see why the answer to your framed question is just the torus and the Klein bottle?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the question. It is definitely the uniformization theorem that you need (see the link in my earlier comment).

Comment: @RobArthan: The wiki link seems useful! I quote from there "...the uniformization theorem leads to a classification of Riemann surfaces into three types: those that have the Riemann sphere as universal cover ("elliptic"), those with the plane as universal cover ("parabolic") and those with the unit disk as universal cover ("hyperbolic")."
Under this classification, what is the set of spaces with parabolic universal cover? Is it only the torus and the klein bottle?

Comment: It follows for instance from the Gauss-Bonnet theorem: Since curvature in this case is identically zero, so is the Euler characteristic. Then it follows from the classification of surfaces that the only surfaces of zero Euler characteristic are the torus and the Klein bottle.

Comment: See also my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373526/prove-that-closed-orientable-riemann-surfaces-are-hyperbolic-pecicely-when-their/2374235#2374235

Comment: Thanks @MoisheKohan, I think that might be what I'm looking for. As I'm reading up more about this, I came across [this](https://willierushrush.github.io/posts/2020/07/classification/) that states that every connected Reimann surface $X$ that is covered by the complex plane is the plane, the complex cylinder or the complex torus. Why is the Klein bottle missing in this characterization? Or is that included in some way that I am missing? And when they say that the cover is $\mathbb{C}$ is there an implicit assumption that the pullback metric is isometric to the Euclidean plane as you framed it?

Comment: @SarthakC: Klein bottle cannot have a Riemann surface structure since Riemann surfaces (and complex manifolds in general) are all orientable. There is a way, however, to incorporate nonorientable surfaces in this theory.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: A question as I'm studying to understand your comment better: "Which compact surfaces admit Riemannian metrics such that the universal cover with pull-back metric is isometric to the Euclidean plane? ... "only the torus and the Klein bottle."" The pullback metric (as defined in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2849081/162285)) from the torus up to R2 would be different from the usual Euclidean metric, no? Two far away points on the plane would have a short distance on the torus? Also, do make this an answer and I will accept it! I think it's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @SarthakC: It depends on what you mean by "different": it would be isometric. Bur isometric metrics on the same manifold can be different in the sense that you mentioned.  Differential geometers frequently regard isometric metrics as "the same ". I will add an answer later...

Comment: In the meantime, you may want to read my answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87503/isometric-embedding/3590019#3590019 on two notions of the word "metric" and "isometric" in Riemannian geometry, since you might be confusing the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make sense of your question one has to specify what do "space" and "cover" mean. Without further adjectives, they usually mean "a topological space" and "a topological covering map." However, it is clear from your comments, this is not what you are actually interested in. One can define the notion of a covering in other categories of "spaces," for instance, for triangulated manifolds, complex manifolds, and for Riemannian manifolds.  Let me first discuss the case of Riemannian manifolds. I will assume that you know at least basic Riemannian geometry. Given a connected Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ (where $g$ is the Riemannian metric tensor on $M$, aka a **Riemannian metric**), and a local diffeomorphism
$$
f: N\to M
$$
one defines the **pull-back Riemannian metric** $h=f^*(g)$ on $N$ by the rule
$$
h(u,v)=g(Df_p(u), Df_p(v)), p\in N, u, v\in T_xM.
$$
When we equip $N$ with the Riemannian metric $h$, the map
$$
f: (N, h)\to (M, g)
$$
becomes a (Riemannian) isometric map. This does not mean, of course, that $f$ preserves the Riemannian distance function on $N$, only that $Df$ preserves the inner product on tangent spaces. Now, suppose that $(M,g)$ is a compact Riemannian surface (which is not the same as a **Riemann surface**). Let $f: \tilde M\to M$ denote the universal covering map. One can then pull-back the Riemannian metric $g$ to $\tilde M$, $h:= f^*(g)$. One then can ask for conditions under which $(\tilde M, h)$ is isometric to the Euclidean plane (equipped with the standard flat Riemannian metric $dx^2 + dy^2$). An isometry in the sense of Riemannian geometry **in this case** is the same as an isometry in the sense of metric geometry, i.e. it will preserve the Riemannian distance function. (Differential geometers frequently regard isometric Riemannian manifolds as "the same". I will adopt this viewpoint.) It turns out that there are several equivalent conditions for $(\tilde M, h)$ to be isometric to the Euclidean plane (with the standard flat metric),
one of which is that the Gaussian curvature of the metric $g$ is identically zero (i.e. the metric $g$ is **flat**). Gauss-Bonnet formula then implies that $\chi(M)=0$, i.e. that $M$ is diffeomorphic to the torus or to the Klein bottle. Conversely, both torus and the Klein bottle admit flat Riemannian metrics. Thus, one obtains:

Theorem. A compact connected surface $M$ admits a Riemannian metric $g$ such that the universal cover of $(M,g)$ (equipped with the pull-back Riemannian metric) is isometric to $(\mathbb R^2, dx^2 + dy^2)$ if and only if $M$ is diffeomorphic (equivalently, homeomorphic) to the torus or the Klein bottle. Moreover, if $(M,g)$ is a flat compact connected surface, then the universal cover of $M$ (equipped with the pull-back Riemannian metric) is isometric to
$(\mathbb R^2, dx^2 + dy^2)$.

Is it enough for your purposes? Maybe. Or maybe not. It might be the case that you are actually not dealing with smooth surfaces and instead you are dealing with triangulated surfaces $M$. Accordingly, instead of a Riemannian metric on such a surface, you are dealing with a **piecewise-Euclidean metric**, i.e. a metric (understood in the sense of metric geometry, i.e. a distance function) on each 2-dimensional simplex of the triangulation, such that each simplex is isometric to a simplex in the Euclidean plane (equipped with the "standard" distance function). Furthermore, whenever two 2-dimensional simplices $\Delta_1, \Delta_2$  share an edge $e$, the length of $e$ computed in terms of the metric on $\Delta_1$ is the same as the length of $e$ computed    in terms of the metric on $\Delta_2$. Such substitute for a Riemannian metric appears frequently in applied differential geometry and data science. Given the above data (a triangulation together with a metric on each simplex) one defines a **path-metric** $d$ on the surface $M$, computed by minimizing the arc-length of piecewise-linear paths between the given pair of points in $M$. Furthermore, given the universal covering $f: \tilde M\to M$, one can **pull-back** the triangulation from $M$ to $\tilde M$ and, accordingly, equip each 2-dimensional simplex $\tilde \Delta$ in $\tilde M$ with a metric such that the restriction map
$$
f: \tilde \Delta\to \Delta=f(\tilde \Delta)\subset M
$$
is an isometry. (This is an analogue of taking the pull-back of a Riemannian metric.) Now, one can ask various questions about the geometry of $\tilde M$ equipped with this structure. For instance, one can consider $\tilde d$, the path-metric on $\tilde M$ defined as before. The map
$$
f: (\tilde M, \tilde d)\to (M,d)
$$
is **not** an isometry in the sense of metric geometry. Nevertheless, it preserves lengths of paths and restricts to an isometry on each 2-dimensional simplex. One can ask for conditions under which $(\tilde M, \tilde d)$ (as a metric space) is isometric to the Euclidean plane with the standard distance function. The answer will be pretty much the same as in the Riemannian setting: If and only if the **combinatorial curvature** of $M$ is zero, i.e. the total angle around each vertex of the triangulation is $2\pi$. It will imply, again, that $M$ is either homeomorphic to the torus or the Klein bottle. In practice, zero curvature is too much to ask and one can ask for some softer conditions. For instance, one can consider the graph in $\tilde M$ given by its triangulation. (I will assume that this graph is infinite, equivalently, that $\tilde M$ is noncompact.) One defines the random walk on this graph, for instance, by declaring the transition probability to be the same for all edges. Then one can ask for the random walk to be **recurrent**, i.e., that with probability 1 it returns to every given compact subset infinitely often. This, turns out again imply that $M$ is homeomorphic to the torus or the Klein bottle. Moreover, while $\tilde M$ in our setting does not have a natural Riemannian metric (because the total angles at vertices need not be $2\pi$), it has a canonical complex structure and one can ask if this Riemann surface is conformally isomorphic (biholomorphic) to the complex plane. This again turns out to be equivalent to the assumption that the random walk is recurrent, and, equivalently, that $M$ is homeomorphic to the torus or the Klein bottle.

I stop here since my answer is already too long...

Comment: This has been an extremely illuminating answer. One clarifying question: You stated "An isometry in the sense of Riemannian geometry in *this* case is the same as an isometry in the sense of metric geometry". What does the *this* refer to? Are you referring to $f:(\tilde M,h)\to(M,g)$ or the isometry between $(\tilde M,h)$ and the Euclidean plane? 
When do the two types of isometry coincide? Clearly not in the universal cover mapping to the torus/klein bottle?

Comment: @SarthakC: A bijective map between two connected Riemannian manifolds is an isometry in the sense of metric geometry if and only if it is a Riemannian isometry. This theorem is nontrivial, it is due to Steenrod and Myers.

Comment: I see. So if I understand correctly, you are saying there that $\tilde M$ (with the pullback metric from $M,g$) is isometric in the Riemannian sense to the flat Euclidean plane, and is hence also isometric in the geometric sense to the Euclidean plane?

Comment: This has been very helpful. I will be citing this answer in what I am writing, and would like to thank you for this discussion in the acknowledgements. I will use your screen name, do let me know in case you would rather I use any alternate name.

Comment: Right..........